# I would like to know how this PNG image was created

Tags: jquery, png

I received an email today with what seems to be an animated PNG image. When I looked into it further, I found that the image was getting updated and so simply cannot be an animated GIF renamed to a PNG.

Here is the image:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how this works?

When viewing the email on a live account the timer goes down. In Outlook it doesn't have the same effect. But when you re-open the email, the image is refreshed with a new time.

Stumped!!

Comment: If you have a Linux/Unix use the "file" command, it tells you everything about the type of the files.

Comment: why jquery tag is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an "animated PNG", it's a GIF file with a wrong extension. The first few bytes read

```
47 49 46 38 39 61 6C 01 8B 00 70 00 00 21 F9 GIF89al..‹.p..!.
```

Animating PNGs is possible, but it's a non-standard extension to the standard. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG for more information on this file format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So how does it constantly count down without resetting itself to a start point? I am guessing it will have to have a start point of say, 50 days

Comment: It uses the common Graphic Extension `21:F9` ([description](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html#gceb)) for a one-time animation. It does not reset to the starting image; you will see that it stops counting down after 30-or-so images. Quite possibly, when viewed online the web page gets refreshed in the background so you have the *illusion* it keeps on counting down.